# React Router V6 reloads application on URL pathname change. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, redux-toolkit

I have an application that I created using create React App. I am using React Router Dom v6 and Redux Toolkit. So far the application behaves exactly how I want it to EXCEPT for when I enter an expected pathname into the url. The whole state is reset (Redux will reset store on page reload) and that is not the behavior I want nor is it what I was expecting React Router to do. The only partial solution I could find was changing the type of router I used from Browser Router to Hash Router. Doing this works up until I navigate to the same URL as the current URL. (Navigation is done by re-entering the same pathname in url). I have spent way too much time trying to figure why this is happening and have nothing to show for it. Is there any one out there that can explain?

Link to a GIF of my bug:
[https://imgur.com/a/gjAJlFt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0Y1A.gif)

Index.js:

```
 const container = document.getElementById('root');
 const root = createRoot(container);

 const router = createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(
        <Route path='/' element={<App/>}>
          <Route index path='starred' element={<ArticleList/>}/>
          <Route index path='latest' element={<ArticleList/>}/>
        </Route>
    )
)

root.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <RouterProvider router={router}/>
    </Provider>
);
```

App.js:

```
function App() {
    const Outlet = useOutlet();
    const theme = useSelector(state => state.theme.getTheme);

    return (
      <div className='App' data-theme={theme}>
         <Header/>
         { Outlet ?? <ArticleList/>}
         <Footer/>
      </div>

    );
  }
```

Header.js : This is where I have Link's in order to navigate through my application without reloading the page.

```
export default function Header() {
const activeStyle = {
    color: 'coral',
};
const inactiveStyle = {
    'fontSize':'small',
}

const matches = useMatches();
return (
    <div className='header-nav'>
        <div>
            <NavLink to='/'>
                <i className="fa-brands fa-3x fa-hacker-news" ></i>
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1> Hacker News </h1>
        </div>
        <div className='header-space'>
            <span>
            <NavLink 
                style={({ isActive }) =>
                matches.length === 1 || isActive ? activeStyle : inactiveStyle
                }
                to='latest' end>latest</NavLink>
            </span>  |   
            <span>
            <NavLink
                style={({ isActive }) =>
                isActive ? activeStyle : inactiveStyle
                }
                to='starred'>starred</NavLink>

            </span>
       </div>
        <ToggleTheme/>
    </div>
)
```

}

ArticleList.js:

```
export default function ArticleList() {
const {
    data: articleIds, 
} = useGetIdsQuery();

const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
const [starredIndex, setStarredIndex] = useState(0);
const location = useMatches();
const starredIds = useSelector(articlesSelector.selectIds);
const isStarred = location.find(({pathname}) => pathname === '/starred')?.pathname === '/starred';
const displayArticles = isStarred ? starredIds?.slice(starredIndex, starredIndex + 12) : articleIds?.slice(index, index + 12);

const onClickHandler = () => {
    if(displayArticles.length < 12) return; 
    if(isStarred) {
        const nextPage = starredIndex + 12;
        setStarredIndex(nextPage);
    }
    const nextPage = index + 12;
    setIndex(nextPage)

}
return (
    <div>
        <ol className="list-groupMine">
        {displayArticles?.map((id)=> <Article key={id} id={id}/>)}
        </ol> 
        <div className='show-more'>
            <button className='showMoreButton' onClick={onClickHandler}> show more </button>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

}

Article.js:

```
export default function Article({id}){
const { data } = useGetArticleQuery(id ?? skipToken);
const { url, title, score, kids, by } = data?.entities[id] ?? {};
const domain =  url ? new URL(url) : undefined;
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const selectEntities = useSelector(articlesSelector.selectEntities); 
const isSaved = selectEntities[id]?.saved === 'saved' ? 'saved' : 'save';
const onClickHandler = () => {
    if(selectEntities[id]) {
        return dispatch(removeSaved(id));
    }
    dispatch(addSaved({...data?.entities[id], saved:'saved' }));
}

return(
    <div className="spacer">
        <div>
            <span >
                <a href={url} style={{'fontFamily': 'monospace'}} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{title}</a>
            </span>
            <span>
                <a className={"extra-inline-style"} href={url} style={{ 'color':'grey',}} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{`(${domain?.host.replace('www.','') ?? ''})`}</a>     
            </span>
        </div>
        <div className="subtext">
        <p>
            {`${score} points by ${by} `}
            |{` ${kids?.length ?? 0} comments `}
            | {isSaved === 'saved'? <BsStarFill style={{'color': 'orange'}} onClick={onClickHandler}/> : <BsStar  onClick={onClickHandler}/> }
            <span>{' ' + isSaved}</span>
            </p>

        </div>
    </div>
)
```

}

I'm omitting store code for the moment because I am not sure that it's relevant to my question since issue is with react router?

Comment: Is your Redux Store defined inside each Route? If yes, try moving it to the very top of the tree. Also,  nobody can tell you what's wrong with the code, we can't see. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem. To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and its linked resources

Comment: This is how browsers work. Manually entering/changing the URL via the address bar is the same as making a new request to the server for the page. In other words, doing this will ***always*** reload the page and React app. Use `react-router-dom` links and navigation actions to navigate around the app. For the cases where the page is reloaded, are you wanting to load *some* persisted state so it's not reset?

Comment: @vighnesh153 Thank you for the tips. I've updated my question to include my react code for right now.  I believe my store is at the very top of the tree?

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you. I guess I didn't realize that entering a url would reload the entire page each time. How is it that in using a Hash Router it doesn't cause the page to reload?

Comment: I don't see issues with the routing/navigation code. Is not working as expected? If it is working, then why are you manually changing the path in the address bar? Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you are saying is an issue.

Comment: "How is it that in using a Hash Router it doesn't cause the page to reload?" The hash is ignored by servers, so perhaps your browser is using a cached result of the URL (domain + path). I wonder if you check the "disable cache" option in the network tab in the dev tools if it'd behave more like a regular page request.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/gjAJlFt I made a gif of the error. Lmk if it's accessible to you. What is happening is that when I enter the /starred path in url I will not see any of the stars I had previously saved due to the entire page reloading and redux wiping store because of it. Disabling cache in network tab did not work.@DrewReese

Comment: When you manually enter a url in the address bar, it will reload the page. This is expected behaviour. Imagine you share this link with someone. They should be able to see the data. The store is reset when you reload a page. You should look at how you can re-fetch the data on different tabs. From the image you shared above, it looks like you are only fetching the data on the "latest" tab and not on the "starred" tab.

Comment: If you simply want to persist the redux state so it's maintained through page reloads then I suggest resisting the store to localStorage and initializing it from localStorage, or use [redux-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist) that does much of this for you. It's about a 5-15 minute integration, depending on your familiarity.

Comment: @DrewReese thank you for your insight and help! Persisting state with local storage worked. All the best!

Comment: @vighnesh153 Thank you for your help. I used local storage to persist my data. Not sure if I'm allowed to fo this here but here are two linkesto my repo and now working app if you have any sort of feedback to offer. Thanks and all the best!https://alejandrafranc0.github.io/hacker-news-makeover/
https://github.com/alejandraFranc0/hacker-news-makeover